# Unable to see JSON conversion error in Spring MVC REST

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I am doing AngularJS and Spring REST application.
Here is my code.

```
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping("/user")
  // @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
  public class UserController
  {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/verifyUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Boolean verifyUser(@RequestBody User user)
    {
    }
  }
```

If     `user` object is not in correct format then browser says     `400 (Bad Request)`
No other error is displayed in Eclipse console. I just want to see what exact error occured in deserialization  if     `user` object is in incorrect format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert your method like below. Use ObjectMapper to convert the JSON to the object,so while converting it will throw exception and you will be able to identify the problem.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/verifyUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Boolean verifyUser(@RequestBody String json)
    {  
       try{
           ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
           User user = om.readValue(json, User.class);
          } 
          catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace()
          }
         // Write your logic.....
        return ....;       

    }
```

Comment: How do we have two [**MadProgrammer**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer)s?

Comment: @peeskillet sorry i am unable to get your point,have i answered sth wrong?

Comment: No, it's just SO has another MadProgrammer. That's all I wanted to point out :-D

Comment: Is there another way to see the errors or error-logs of spring? I want to use spring default objectMapper!

Comment: In logback.xml file you can add      <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to use the custom objectMapper or you don't want to use `String` as method input, you can use spring `ExceptionHandler`. Simply add the following method into your controller and then you can see the jackson databind errors in your console.

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason="There was an error processing the request body.")
public void handleMessageNotReadableException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpMessageNotReadableException exception) {
    System.out.println("\nUnable to bind post data sent to: " + request.getRequestURI() + "\nCaught Exception:\n" + exception.getMessage());
}
```

spring documentation:  [Expception handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

If you want to ignore some useless jackson exceptions, you can use your own jackson ObjectMapper in the springframework. just see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739972/how-to-get-geojson-from-spring-rest-controller/29742775#29742775).

Comment: This looks more appropriate solution.